# Unitary matrix with UnitaryMatrixQ

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

In the Mathematica help, the following example for a symbolic 2$\times$2 matrix

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$,

with constraints, $c=b^{*}$ and $d=-a^{*}$ is given. My goal is to check the unitarity of a 3$\times$3 matrix using the UnitarityMatrixQ command. The code and output is in the following:

```
Block[{c = Conjugate[b], d = -Conjugate[a]}, 
  UnitaryMatrixQ[
    {{a, b}, {c, d}} / Sqrt[Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2], 
    SameTest -> (FullSimplify[#1 - #2] == 0 &)
  ]
]
```

(* True *)

How to extend this solution for a 3$\times$3 matrix?

Comment: What have you tried? What conditions would you like to impose in the case of the 3D matrix? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is much more complicated than the 2 dim case. There are now 6 independent parameters. See e.g.: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1802/1802.00196.pdf

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to give some context rather than just some sterile toy-model code to be extended to more complicated cases!

Comment: @MarcoB: I have tried the 2$\times$2 case as shown above. I want to get the same thing but for 3$\times$3 symbolic matrix.

Comment: @DanielHuber: Parameterization in terms of trigonometric functions is already clear. I wonder about the general symbolic as shown for the 2$\times$2 case above.

Comment: @bmf: If you run the above code, you see the output is True. My question is what are the relations between the parameters for 3$\times$3  just like for the case of 2$\times$2 case as c= b* and d=-a*.

Comment: @SciJewel yes, I got it. Thanks for the comment. All I am saying is that a self-contained and explanatory question is always more helpful for everyone. For instance, you could explain what the code does, what the conditions offer to the matrix etc.

Comment: @bmf: You are right, but I was unable to write the code. In fact, I wanted to write a 2$\times$2 matrix explicitly before the code above in a general form.

Comment: Doesn't `UnitaryMatrixQ[matrix, SameTest -> (FullSimplify[#1 - #2] == 0 &)]` work on your `matrix`?